# Как найти сумму элементов вещественной матрицы

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы, динамические-массивы

```
// . Вычислить сумму элементов вещественной матрицы, находящихся между минимальным и максимальным элементами. Создать функции для:
//¬ определения номера минимального элемента +
//¬ определения номера максимального элемента +
//¬ определения суммы.
// если 1 максимальных и 1 минимальных элементов несколько найти сумму элементов раположеннх между первым минимальным и первым максимальным 

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int minimum(int** mas, int n, int m) {
    int min = mas[0][0];
    int str = 1;
    int srl = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if (min > mas[i][j]) {
                min = mas[i][j];
                str = i + 1;
                srl = j + 1;
            }

    }

    cout << "Минимальный номер элемента в массиве\t" << str << srl << endl;
    return str, srl;

}

int maximum(int** mas, int n, int m) {
    int max = mas[0][0];
    int str1 = 0;
    int srl1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if (max < mas[i][j]) {
                max = mas[i][j];
                str1 = i + 1;
                srl1 = j + 1;
            }

    }

    cout << "Максимальный  номер элемента в массиве\t" << str1 << srl1 << endl;
    return str1, srl1;


}
void sum (int str,  int srl, int str1, int srl1) {

}



int main() {
    int n, m;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    cout << "Вводите матрицу" << endl;
    cin >> n >> m;
    cout << "Вводите значения" << endl;
    int** mas = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mas[i] = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cin >> mas[i][j];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "(";
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << mas[i][j];
        cout << ")" << endl;
    }
    int str, srl = minimum(mas, n, m);
    int str1, srl1 = maximum(mas, n, m);
}
```

Дан двумерный массив. Вывести номера максимальных и минимальных элементов(это я сделал). И найти сумму между минимальным и максимальными элементам. Подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы использовал такой прекрасный инструмент языка С++ - STL

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int RowSize, int ColumnSize>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix() {
        std::cout << "Please, enter elements for matrix!" << std::endl;
        fillMatrix();
    }

    template<int RowSize2, int ColumnSize2>
    bool operator==(Matrix<RowSize2, ColumnSize2> matrix) {
    // Хотел тут продемонстрировать пользу использования шаблонов, 
    // но к задаче это неотносится
        if constexpr (RowSize != RowSize2) {
            std::cout << "Row sizes of matrices are different";
            return false;
        } else if (ColumnSize != ColumnSize2) {
            std::cout << "Column sizes of matrices are different";
            return false;
        } else {

        }
    }

    int getMaxElement() const {
        std::vector<int> max_elements_over_all_rows(RowSize);

        std::transform(matrix_.begin(), matrix_.end(), max_elements_over_all_rows.begin(), [](const auto& row) {
            return *std::max_element(row.begin(), row.end());
        });

        return *std::max_element(max_elements_over_all_rows.begin(), max_elements_over_all_rows.end());
    }

    int getMinElement() const {
        std::vector<int> max_elements_over_all_rows(RowSize);

        std::transform(matrix_.begin(), matrix_.end(), max_elements_over_all_rows.begin(), [](const auto& row) {
            return *std::min_element(row.begin(), row.end());
        });

        return *std::min_element(max_elements_over_all_rows.begin(), max_elements_over_all_rows.end());
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix_ = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(RowSize, std::vector<int>(ColumnSize));

    void fillMatrix() {
        for(int i = 0; i < RowSize; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < ColumnSize; j++) {
                int value;
                std::cin >> value;

                matrix_.at(i).at(j) = value;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Matrix<2, 2> matrix;

    std::cout << matrix.getMaxElement() << std::endl;
    std::cout << matrix.getMinElement() << std::endl;
}
```

Прошу прощения, что решение получилось громоздким. В угловых скобочках указываете размерность матрицы. При конструкции матрицы от Вас требуется ее заполнить, иначе программа не продолжит работу

Answer (score 1):

Ну, суммировать можно примерно так:

```
int sum (int** mas, int m, int str,  int srl, int str1, int srl1)
{
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = str*m+srl+1; i <str1*m+srl1; ++i)
        s += mas[i/m][i%m];
    return s;
}
```

Только вот тут у нас С++, а значит, такое -

```
return str, srl;
```

будет работать не так, как вы думаете... (читай об операторе запятая)

```
void minimum(int** mas, int n, int m, int& str, int& srl) 
{
    int min = mas[0][0];
    str = srl = 0;
     ....
    if (min > mas[i][j]) {
        min = mas[i][j];
            str = i;
            srl = j;
```

Ну, и для максимума переписать аналогично... И вызывать надо как

```
int str, srl;
minimum(mas, n, m, str, srl);
```